# Word wrapping and line breaks in Korean

Tags: formatting

Korean allows words to be split in the middle at the end of lines, and I've always thought that line breaks could appear at any point in the middle of a word.
However, [this blog post by a professional translator](http://nojeokhill.koreanconsulting.com/2015/05/korean-translation-tip-applying-the-cardinal-rules-of-korean-language-layout-to-microsoft-powerpoint.html) seems to indicate otherwise - at least, it says that an instance of 이렇게 split like this:

> .....이렇 
>   게 .......

is an incorrect break.

What are the rules for line breaks in Korean?  That is, when is it not permissible to put a line break in the middle of a Korean word?

Comment: The article does not mean the break is incorrect. Break in between a word is always acceptable. The article just points out that the PowerPoint will mark such a break as wrong as the grammar check is in en-US, and you need to change the language to Korean in order to prevent the checker from correcting you

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy  The article says the red underlined parts are incorrectly marked wrong, but the word 이렇게 is incorrectly split up: "the blue arrow shows a Korean word split incorrectly at the end of the line."

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to wrap correctly, depending on formatting:

- **Left aligned text** (ragged edges): split only on spaces between words
- **Justified text**: split anywhere

I'm not sure the origin of this rule: it might just be this translator's personal preference. (This was the first time I heard of such a rule; I've just noticed Korean words split anywhere.) [In the words of the professional translator you referenced](http://nojeokhill.koreanconsulting.com/2013/05/korean-translation-tip-cardinal-rules-of-korean-language-layout.html):

> - When laying out the body text, either left- AND right-justify the text OR make sure you end each line of text between words, not in the
>   middle of words.
> - In titles or short phrases and bullet points, don’t left- or right-justify; just make sure you end each line of text between words,
>   not in the middle of words.
>
> [image]